# How to bind a string array of properties in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have the following in my application.properties file

```
some.server.url[0]=http://url
some.server.url[1]=http://otherUrl
```

How do I refer to the array of properties using the @Value anotation inside a @Bean method?

I am using Java 6 with Tomcat 7 and Spring boot 1.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow these steps

1) 
@Value("${some.server.url}")
private List urls;

2)
@ConfigurationProperties("some.server")
public class SomeConfiguration {

3)
You should have getter and setter for instance variable 'urls'

Comment: I found that the accepted answer (2) was not correct: 1. The java name has to match **exactly** the name in the properties file, i.e. inputQueues[0] and so on in properties file needs a variable name inputQueues. Very important: you have to create an instance of the list like List<String> inputQueues = new ArrayList<>(); 2. You don't need a prefix 3. You need the annotation @ConfigurationProperties 4. You need the setters/getters 5. You don't need the $Value annotation.

Answer (score 28):

I was also having the same problem as you mentioned and it seems using index form on **`application.properties`** was not working for me either.

To solve the problem I did something like below

```
some.server.url = url1, url2
```

Then to get the those properties I simply use **`@Value`**

```
@Value("${some.server.url}")
private String[] urls ;
```

**Spring** automatically **splits** the String with **comma** and return you an **Array**. <kbd>AFAIK</kbd> this was introduced in `Spring 4+`

If you don't want **`comma (,)`** as seperator you have to use **SpEL** like below.

```
@Value("#{'${some.server.url}'.split(',')}")
private List<String> urls;
```

where **`split()`** accepts the **seperator**

Comment: Also use `Arrays.asList(urls)` afterwards if you prefer a List instead.

Comment: Works. For yaml, just put hyphen based values on each line

Answer (score 8):

You can use a collection.

```
@Value("${some.server.url}")
private List<String> urls;
```

You can also use a configuration class and inject the bean into your other class:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("some.server")
public class SomeConfiguration {
    private List<String> url;

    public List<String> getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(List<String> url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Bean
 public List<URI> someUriList(@Value("${some.server.url}") List<String> urlList)`
returns
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'some.server.url' in string value "${some.server.url}"`

Comment: Based on your question you had the property as `some.url` not `some.server.url`. Is that the issue?

Comment: No. I have updated the initial example to reflect what is my application.properties

Comment: Not sure why that isn't working for you but I have also included another way to do it and you can see if that works better for you.

Comment: Using Java 6 with Tomcat 7 and Spring boot 1.4. Has that got anything to do with it?

Comment: In your example `@ConfigurationProperties("some.server")` I have other properties under some.server that do not belong in the url array.

Comment: That's fine... They just won't be used in the context of that bean. If you want them assigned as well then include properties for them and they will be populated.