# Workaround to using @ImportResource for XML config files

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jakarta-ee

I am developing an application that runs on Spring Boot configured via XML. For modularity, I didn't want to use @ImportResource as it requires me to go into the source code when in XML configuration I can just configure the XML files to change dependencies.

The problem is that I'm using Spring Boot to run my Spring MVC Controllers *(@Controller)* and for me to make use of the dependencies I configured in my XML files, I need to declare @ImportResource, which I don't want to use.

Is there any workaround to not use @ImportResource while still using XML config files to inject the dependencies in my Spring MVC Controllers?

Comment: Hint: `@ImportResource` can also take a pattern/wildcards... Also has nothing to do with XML or Java you could achieve the same with Java based configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using spring boot and you are ok with mentioning the config location in application properties, you can do this in application.properties

```
config:
  location: file:///config.xml
```

And the you can use this property in your `@ImportResource`

```
@ImportResource("${config.location}")
```

This way you can avoid changes to the source code, while still using xml configuration.

Comment: This seems alright. How do I do this with multiple locations?

Comment: `config.location[0]: location1`,`config.location[1]: location2`.  Maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46185767/5189158

Comment: I'm sorry but the @ImportResource doesn't recognize the different config.locations I set.

Comment: Nevermind. What I did was that I just used one XML config file where all the other config files could be loaded to. But thank you still! [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113579/how-to-import-spring-config-xml-of-one-project-into-spring-config-xml-of-another]